# OverviewTable method displays additional records when called multiple times

Tags: c#, console

I'm currently learning C# and for an excersise we needed to code a console app where the user provide a starttime, endtime and then the diffrence between them is calculated by the program. All values are stored into a sqlite database.
One of the functions we need to implement is an overview of the table that prints all records in the table. This needs to be done by using the NuGet Package ConsoleTableExt. (https://github.com/minhhungit/ConsoleTableExt)
So I wrote this method 'OverviewTable' and when this method is called the first time everything is fine. The table displays the column names and all the records inside the table like it should.

However when the OverviewTable method is called a second time or more the output looks like this: table title + Column names, the first 5 records, table title + column names again and then all the records. When called a third time the first 5 records are shown twice followed by the entire table, when called again the first 5 records are shown 3times and so on for each call.

```
internal static void OverviewTable(string connectionString)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            string sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM CodeTracker";
            List<CodingSession> sessions = new List<CodingSession>();
            sessions.Clear();
            sessions = BuildList(connectionString, sqlCommand);
            PrintTable(sessions);
        }
internal static void PrintTable(List<CodingSession> sessions)
        {
            ConsoleTableBuilder
                .From(sessions)
                .WithTitle("Coding Tracker")
                .WithColumn("Id", "Start", "End", "Time")
                .WithFormatter(1, f => $"{f:dd/MM/yy HH:MM}")
                .WithFormatter(2, f => $"{f:dd/MM/yy HH:MM}")
                .WithFormatter(3, f => $@"{f:hh\:mm}")
                .ExportAndWriteLine();
        }
```

I have no idea why the first 5 records are being shown extra for each extra call.

- I asked for help on the discord channel of the course I'm following, but none of my fellow students seems to see the problem nor the creator of the course.
- I also asked ChatGPT, it suggested to add the sessions.Clear() line before building the sessions list so no records from previous calls could remain. But that didn't solve the problem. Didn't get more usefull info out of it other than that.
- Ofcourse I tried to debug it myself by putting a breakpoint and following the flow of the program. Everything seems fine there, the database contains 19 records and session stores all these 19 records. Even when called multiple times, sessions always stays at 19 records. It's not that the 5 first records are added to it.

Comment: Are you on Linux? The Console.Clear() Method may not be clearing the full Console buffer, just the visible screen. Try changing the size of the console before running and see if it outputs differently

Comment: I'm on a windows 11 computer. Changing the size of the console windows did indeed solve it. Thanks for the answer.